# Can I use ~/.config/ instead of ~/ for arbitrary packages?

Tags: fedora, xdg, xdg-user-dirs

I read [very little about xdg](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html), probably just enough to be dangerous. From what I've seen online, it looks like the new cool thing is to put specification files for X in `~/.config/` instead of just `~/` and prepending them with a dot. I'm super into this as currently `ls -a ~ | grep ^[.]` returns 32 files cluttering my home directory.

Is there a way to force things to use or work with `~/.config/` instead of `~/`?

I thought fedora was supposed to be cutting edge, but even [its fonts file for X lives in `~/.fonts`](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-x-fonts.html) and there doesn't seem to be a way to get it to deal with `~/.config/fonts` instead. Can I configure this?

If there's some resource I was supposed to have read instead of asking this question, feel free to point me at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are free to use `~/.config` for your own programs, as well as any other location you like.

For existing programs, they already have a default location for their config files, you can't change that without recompiling them.
They may support an option to read their configuration from an alternate location. But that means that for each program you have to lookup the documentation and change the invocation everywhere.

Comment: One can also make use of symbolic links.

Comment: @JdeBP, symbolic links would still mean that my home directory would have all the `~/.special_config_file` files which makes it less helpful for my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Applications following the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) can have their default directories modified by setting [a number of environment variables](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables).

For example, if the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable is empty, a value of `$HOME/.config` will be used.

If you want to have non-XDG-aware tools pick up configuration files from `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, then you would need to configure them individually to do this.

For example, the `.vimrc` file of Vim could be placed in `$HOME/.config/vim` and referred to with

```
export MYVIMRC="${XGD_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/vim/.vimrc"
```

or

```
export VIM="${XGD_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/vim"
```

Comment: So there's no requirements that X tools follow XDG documentation / specifications? It's just best practice that we hope people adhere to?

Comment: @jeremysprofile Most of the X tools I use were written before XDG was even a thing. As with all standards, they are never enforced unless there is some compliance mechanism that implementers are willing to commit to.